# Animation in Css Buttions

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, animation

I created an animation in my CSS file. But I need some improvement and I am unable to find how to do it.

Let's take the example of the "funny button" (the class name 'train3') first it is at position 40em from the right and when the animation starts it goes to complete right and then it again comes to its older position

The change I want to make is "funny button" at starting should be at the complete left and when animation start's then it should come to its original position (which is 40em from right) and then it should stay there until I reload the page.

My code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,400i,600,600i');
  html,body{
    margin:0;
    height:120%;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}
  a{
    text-decoration:none
  }
  .header{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height:50vw;
    min-height:600px;
    max-height:100%;
    min-width:300px;
    color:#eee;
  }
  .header:after{
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.12) 40%,rgba(27,32,48,1) 100%);
  }
  .header:before{
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:300%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); backface-visibility: hidden;
    scale(1.0, 1.0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
    background:#1B2030 url(asthetic_Bg_Image1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    animation: grow 360s  linear 10ms infinite;
    transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    z-index:-2
  }
  .header a{
    color:#eee
  }
  .menu{
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:3px;
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
    text-decoration:none
  }
  .menu:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:3px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:5px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    box-shadow:0 8px, 0 16px
  }
  .logo{
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items:center;
    align-content:center;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 12em;
    padding:0px 10px;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:1.1em;
    line-height:1;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:40px
  }
  .sides, .info{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width:50%
  }
  .info{
    width:100%;
    padding:15% 10% 0 10%;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
  }
  .author{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:url(https://i.imgur.com/6DLCsZcb.jpg) center repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin-bottom:3px
  }
  .info h4, .meta{
    font-size:0.7em
  }
  .meta{
    font-style:italic;
  }
  @keyframes grow{
    0% { transform: scale(1) translateY(0px)}
    50% { transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-200px)}
  }
  .content{  
    padding:5% 10%;
    text-align:justify
  }
  button{
    color:#333;
   height: 5px;
    border-radius:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    font-weight:600
  }
  
  .btn{
   
  }
  
  .twtr{
    margin-top:100px
  }.btn.twtr:after{content:"\1F426";padding-left:5px}
  
  .train2 {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example1;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  right: 40em;
  top:10em;
  

  }
  @keyframes example1 {
  0%  { right: 0em;   top: 10em;}
  
  100% { right:40em; top:10em;}
  }
  .train3 {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example3;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  right: 40em;
  top: 15em;
  animation-delay: 2s;  
}
  @keyframes example3 {
  0%   { right:0px; top:15em;}
  100% { right:40em; top:15em;}
  }
  .train4 {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example4;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  left: 35em;
  top: 15em;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  @keyframes example4{
  0%   { left:0px; top:15em;}
  100% { left:35em; top:15em;}
  }
  .train5 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: example5;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    left: 35em;
    top: 21em;
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }
  @keyframes example5{
    0%   { left:0px; top:21em;}
    100% { left:35em; top:21em;}
  }
  .train6 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: example6;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    right: 40em;
    top: 21em;
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }
  @keyframes example6{
    0%   { right:0px; top:21em;}
    100% { right:40em; top:21em;}
  }
  .train31 {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example31;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  right: 40em;
  top: 27em;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  }
  @keyframes example31 {
  0%   { right:0px; top:27em;}
  100% { right:40em; top:27em;}
  }
  .train41 {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example41;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  left: 35em;
  top: 27em;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  }
  @keyframes example41{
  0%   { left:0px; top:27em;}
  100% { left:35em; top: 27 em;}
  }
  .train11{
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example11;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  right: 30em;
  top:32em;
  animation-delay: 14s;
  }
  @keyframes example11 {
  0%   { right:0px; top:32em;}
  100% { right:30em; top:32em;}
  }
  .relax_tab{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
 <body> <div class="header" style="text-align: center;">

    <div class="sides" style="text-align: center;">
      <a href="#" class="logo" style="text-align: center;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="sides"> <a href="#" class="menu"> </a></div>
    <div class="info">
      <h4><a href="#category"></a></h4>
     <a href="#relax_tab"> <button  style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train2">Relax</button></a>
    <a href="#funny"> <button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train3">Funny</button></a>
     <a href="#all_time"> <button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train4">All Time fav.</button></a>
      <a href="#english"><button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train5">English</button></a>
     <a href="#hindi"> <button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train6">Hindi</button></a>
     <a href="#chill"> <button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train31">Chill</button></a>
      <a href="#sad"><button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train41">Sad</button></a>
      <button style="color:#333;
        border:2px solid;
        height: 37px;
        background-color: transparent ;
        color: white;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600" class="train11">Suggestions</button> </body>
```

This is how my website looks I need to show it because it's not responsive

[image]

Comment: Hi, by 'complete left' do you mean right up against the left hand side of the page (viewport) or in the left hand column position (as in the images)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points to note.

The first is that to get the element moving from the complete left but to a position that is defined via its right position (40em) we need to set the initial position in terms of the right also so we use: `right: 100%;`

The second is that to get the element to remain in the `right: 40em` position after the animation we now have to set `animation-fill-mode: forwards` otherwise it will go back to its initial position.

Here's the code just for train3 as discussed in the question. Obviously similar changes can be made for the other elements as required.

```html
<head>
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,400i,600,600i');
      html,body{
        margin:0;
        height:120%;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}
      a{
        text-decoration:none
      }
      .header{
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
        align-content: flex-start;
        height:50vw;
        min-height:600px;
        max-height:100%;
        min-width:300px;
        color:#eee;
      }
      .header:after{
        content:"";
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:-1;
       background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.12) 40%,rgba(27,32,48,1) 100%);
      }
      .header:before{
        content:"";
        width:100%;
        height:300%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); backface-visibility: hidden;
        scale(1.0, 1.0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
        background:#1B2030 url(asthetic_Bg_Image1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        animation: grow 360s  linear 10ms infinite;
        transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        z-index:-2
      }
      .header a{
        color:#eee
      }
      .menu{
        display:block;
        width:40px;
        height:30px;
        border:2px solid #fff;
        border-radius:3px;
        position:absolute;
        right:20px;
        top:20px;
        text-decoration:none
      }
      .menu:after{
        content:"";
        display:block;
        width:20px;
        height:3px;
        background:#fff;
        position:absolute;
        margin:0 auto;
        top:5px;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        box-shadow:0 8px, 0 16px
      }
      .logo{
        border:2px solid #fff;
        border-radius:3px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-flex;
        align-items:center;
        align-content:center;
      position: relative;
      top: 1em;
      left: 12em;
        padding:0px 10px;
        font-weight:900;
        font-size:1.1em;
        line-height:1;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        height:40px
      }
      .sides, .info{
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width:50%
      }
      .info{
        width:100%;
        padding:15% 10% 0 10%;
        text-align:center;
        text-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
      }
      .author{
        display:inline-block;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background:url(https://i.imgur.com/6DLCsZcb.jpg) center repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        margin-bottom:3px
      }
      .info h4, .meta{
        font-size:0.7em
      }
      .meta{
        font-style:italic;
      }
      @keyframes grow{
        0% { transform: scale(1) translateY(0px)}
        50% { transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-200px)}
      }
      .content{  
        padding:5% 10%;
        text-align:justify
      }
      button{
        color:#333;
       height: 5px;
        border-radius:25px;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        font-weight:600
      }
      
      .btn{
       
      }
      
      .twtr{
        margin-top:100px
      }.btn.twtr:after{content:"\1F426";padding-left:5px}
      
      .train2 {
        width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: example1;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      right: 40em;
      top:10em;
      

      }
      @keyframes example1 {
      0%  { right: 0em;   top: 10em;}
      
      100% { right:40em; top:10em;}
      }
      .train3 {
        width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: example3;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      right: 100%; /* changed */
      animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* added to make it stay at the final position */
      top: 15em;
      animation-delay: 2s;  
    }
      @keyframes example3 {
      0%   { right: 100%; top:15em;} /* changed to put it completely left */
      100% { right: 40em; top:15em;}
      }
      .train4 {
        width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: example4;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      left: 35em;
      top: 15em;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      }
      @keyframes example4{
      0%   { left:0px; top:15em;}
      100% { left:35em; top:15em;}
      }
      .train5 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: example5;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        left: 35em;
        top: 21em;
        animation-delay: 6s;
      }
      @keyframes example5{
        0%   { left:0px; top:21em;}
        100% { left:35em; top:21em;}
      }
      .train6 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: example6;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        right: 40em;
        top: 21em;
        animation-delay: 6s;
      }
      @keyframes example6{
        0%   { right:0px; top:21em;}
        100% { right:40em; top:21em;}
      }
      .train31 {
        width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: example31;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      right: 40em;
      top: 27em;
      animation-delay: 10s;
      }
      @keyframes example31 {
      0%   { right:0px; top:27em;}
      100% { right:40em; top:27em;}
      }
      .train41 {
        width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: example41;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      left: 35em;
      top: 27em;
      animation-delay: 10s;
      }
      @keyframes example41{
      0%   { left:0px; top:27em;}
      100% { left:35em; top: 27 em;}
      }
      .train11{
        width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: example11;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      right: 30em;
      top:32em;
      animation-delay: 14s;
      }
      @keyframes example11 {
      0%   { right:0px; top:32em;}
      100% { right:30em; top:32em;}
      }
      .relax_tab{
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
</style>
</head>

    <body> <div class="header" style="text-align: center;">

        <div class="sides" style="text-align: center;">
          <a href="#" class="logo" style="text-align: center;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="sides"> <a href="#" class="menu"> </a></div>
        <div class="info">
          <h4><a href="#category"></a></h4>
         <a href="#relax_tab"> <button  style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train2">Relax</button></a>
        <a href="#funny"> <button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train3">Funny</button></a>
         <a href="#all_time"> <button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train4">All Time fav.</button></a>
          <a href="#english"><button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train5">English</button></a>
         <a href="#hindi"> <button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train6">Hindi</button></a>
         <a href="#chill"> <button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train31">Chill</button></a>
          <a href="#sad"><button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train41">Sad</button></a>
          <button style="color:#333;
            border:2px solid;
            height: 37px;
            background-color: transparent ;
            color: white;
            border-radius:25px;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            font-weight:600" class="train11">Suggestions</button> </body>
```